# How to specify binomial glmm with random and correlation in R?

Tags: r, correlation, binomial-distribution, glmm

I am working on developing a model with a binomial response variable. My data consist of GPS points from tracked animals. The data set is large and contains 15,000 observations from 40 individuals. I would like to develop a GLMM in R that allows for inclusion of 1) the binomial response, 2) random effects, and 3) either spatial or temporal correlation structure. What package will do this? What package will run models quickly? In lme4 and therefore gamm4 it seems there is no easy way to add correlation. Nlme doesn't appear to support binomial models. What do you think?

Comment: you could try INLA or the spaMM package for R.